# PHP SOAP call content type

Tags: php, web-services, soap, header, content-type

I'm attempting to connect with a WS via Soap and struggling with a content type error when I call the method: **content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'**

Below is my code, reducing number of params and hiding url, user and password.

The error happens when I call the ClientRegist() function. I'm convinced I have to pass $params in a different way, but can't find an example anywhere.

```
$url = 'http://---';

$ctx_opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header' => 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml'
  ),
  'username' => '---',
  'password' => '---',
  'trace' => true,
  'exceptions' => true
);

$ctx = stream_context_create($ctx_opts);

$client = new SoapClient($url, array('stream_context' => $ctx));

$params = array(
  'Cardnumber' => $number,
  'Name' => $name
);

try {
  $client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
  $response = $client->ClientRegist($params);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error!<br>";
  echo $e -> getMessage ().'<br>';
  echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try SOAP version 1.2. Its default Content-Type is application/soap+xml

```
<?php

// ...

$client = new SoapClient(
    $url,
    array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, // !!!!!!!
        'stream_context' => $ctx
    )
);
```